# How to expose a gRPC service both as Protobuf and JSON

Tags: grpc, grpc-java

Can we expose gRPC service (in JAVA) with both encoding (Protobuf and JSON)? Like we can do in HTTP+REST, where server creates and set response header basis client `Content-Type :` (`application/json or application/xml or application/proto`).

Comment: Maybe this is what you’re looking for: https://armeria.dev/ (especially https://armeria.dev/docs/server-grpc#unframed-requests)

Answer (score 0):

gRPC supports streaming, which cannot be implemented in HTTP/1. It is not possible to make a gRPC service available as classic HTTP+REST.

Twirp should be pretty close to what you want. It uses plain HTTP/1, is generated from service definitions in .proto files. It only supports unary methods.
https://twitchtv.github.io/twirp/docs/intro.html

gRPC-web is an alternative if you are looking to consume your service with a web browser. It supports unary and server streaming methods. Most importantly, you can use the envoy proxy to make your existing gRPC services available as gRPC-web.

Comment: Or Can we have JSON and ProtoBuf as response Type in gRPC service, so on the basis of client Content-Type, gRPC service can return respective response(JSON/Protobuf).

Comment: Twirp clients can request either JSON or Protobuf. A Twirp server should then respond with the proper type. See https://twitchtv.github.io/twirp/docs/spec_v7.html#requests